# Basic Error Deploy Terrain dApp on LocalTerra

Tags: docker, rust, webassembly, rust-crates, rust-wasm

I've been following this tutorial in order to deploy my first DAPP

https://docs.terra.money/docs/develop/dapp/quick-start/using-terrain-localterra.html

I've ran this in order to install localterra and run docker

```
git clone --branch v0.5.2 --depth 1 https://github.com/terra-money/localterra
cd localterra
docker-compose up
```

Secondly I've scaffolded my dApp

```
 terrain new my-terra-dappcd 
 cd my-terra-dapp 
 npm install
```

I've encountered problems at the third step, the Deploy

When Running

```
 terrain deploy counter --signer validator
```

I get this

How can I possibly solve this error?

Would really appreciate an answer, thank you!

```
 Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.09s
Running script 'optimize': 'docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/code --mount type=volume,source="$(basename "$(pwd)")_cache",target=/code/target --mount type=volume,source=registry_cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry cosmwasm/rust-optimizer:0.12.3
'
Info: RUSTC_WRAPPER=sccache
Info: sccache stats before build
Compile requests                      0
Compile requests executed             0
Cache hits                            0
Cache misses                          0
Cache timeouts                        0
Cache read errors                     0
Forced recaches                       0
Cache write errors                    0
Compilation failures                  0
Cache errors                          0
Non-cacheable compilations            0
Non-cacheable calls                   0
Non-compilation calls                 0
Unsupported compiler calls            0
Average cache write               0.000 s
Average cache read miss           0.000 s
Average cache read hit            0.000 s
Failed distributed compilations       0
Cache location                  Local disk: "/root/.cache/sccache"
Cache size                            0 bytes
Max cache size                       10 GiB
Building contract in /code ...
 Updating crates.io index
Killed
Finished, status of exit status: 137
 Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'artifacts/counter.wasm'
 Code: ENOENT
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems Docker ran out of memory; the tutorial you linked mentions this potential problem, and suggests increasing the amount of memory available to Docker.